# Open playstore app in background

Tags: android, android-intent, start-activity

I want to open play store when i click on button in my app. Play store app is opening on top of my app. But i want my app only to be foreground. Any Solution?

Comment: What do you mean when you say that you want your app to be on foreground?

Comment: If i write startActivity(<playstore intent>), my app going background and play store app coming to foreground. But i want my app should not go out of user's site. It should stay in foreground only but play store app should open in background.